# Probability when removing items from the set

Tags: probability

If I'm thinking of a number from 1 to 12, and give uou a chance to guess it, your chance would be 1/12, right?

If you guess it wrong, and I give you another guess, you probability now increases to 1/11, since you can exclude the previous wrong number.

Now... how can I sum this? I figured that if I gave you 2 chances, your total chance to guess should be 2/12 our 1/6. But since you can exclude the first number before you try the second, shouldn't it be different? Is there a way to sum 1/12 and 1/11?

Comment: The probability of having guessed within two tries is indeed $\frac{2}{12}$ (*assuming you guess two different numbers*).  The probability $\frac{1}{12}$ refers to having guessed correctly on the first guess.  The probability $\frac{1}{11}$ refers to having guessed correctly on the second guess **given that the first guess was incorrect**.  Multiplying by the probability the first was incorrect yields the probability of the correct guess being the second one as $\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{11}=\frac{1}{12}$, so the probability of the guess being correct on first or second is 1/12+1/12=2/12

Comment: I'm sorry... you lost me at: "the probability of the guess being correct on first or second is 1/12+1/12"
How can this be? Shoudn't it be 1/12+1/11?
This should be really simple but I'm having a hard time with this..

Comment: Again, the probability that it is correct on the second guess is *not* $\frac{1}{11}$, it is $\frac{1}{12}$.  The probability your first guess is the correct guess is $\frac{1}{12}$ and the probability your second guess is the correct guess is also $\frac{1}{12}$.  The probability $\frac{1}{11}$ is something related but decidedly different.  The probability $\frac{1}{11}$ is the conditional probability that the second guess is correct given that the first guess was incorrect.  When you add you add the first $\frac{1}{12}$ to the second $\frac{1}{12}$ and get $\frac{2}{12}$ as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{12} + \left( 1- \frac{1}{12}\right)\frac{1}{11}=\frac{2}{12}$$

There are two ways to guess correctly, guess it correctly at the first go: $\frac1{12}$.

Or guess it correctly after the first time, that is make a mistake the first time: $\left( 1- \frac{1}{12}\right)\frac{1}{11}$

Comment: Thank you. I know your answer is perfectly correct, but I'm trying to explain this to a friend in layman's terms and I''m failing to understand the math myself... but thanks anyway!

Comment: [probability tree](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html) might help in explaination.